# Getting started with soap web service client c#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, client

My boss asked how long it would take to build a client to access a web service that will send and receive some basic data and embedded documents. Just starting playing with it to see what's involved. I have been doing web and desktop development for about 20 years but have literally never touched a web service so with that I'm at the extreme newb level.

So far I used the wsdl to create the ServiceReference1 and I can see the methods in intellisense but I don't have the first clue where to start with calling the methods, passing parameters and consuming the response.  I feel stupid because I'm sure it's pretty simple but just flailing at the code and looking for on point examples has gotten me nowhere.  Usually I can find something through google in minutes that is exactly on point but not having luck here.  Would appreciate a push in the right direction.

So basic questions.  Proper way to make the calls. How and where to land the returned data. How to add parameters.

Here is my first attempt.  This gets a simple list and has no parameters. The result in fiddler returns data but there is a runtime type mismatch error which I think is caused by some stray characters leading the response which appear to be caused by chucking, what ever that is. The response starts with **1ffs** every time then contains the remainder of the xml. Secondarily I need to get the list into a dataset or some other container but I was hoping to just be able to step into the code and see a result

```
ServiceReference1.FilingInfoClient webservice = new FilingInfoClient();
        ServiceReference1.courtListRequest cr = new ServiceReference1.courtListRequest();
        ServiceReference1.courtListResponse lr = new ServiceReference1.courtListResponse();
        lr = webservice .getCourtList(cr);
```

This is essentially the same but takes a date param. When I run this fiddler shows the parameter is not being sent. No other errors but I'm sure only because it exploded immediately.

```
    ServiceReference1.FilingInfoClient webservice = new FilingInfoClient();
    ServiceReference1.messageListRequest mr = new ServiceReference1.messageListRequest();
    ServiceReference1.MessageListResponse mlr = new ServiceReference1.MessageListResponse();

    mr.latestMessagePullTimestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
    mr.endTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
    mlr.latestMessagePullTimestamp = DateTime.Now; 
    mlr = webservice.getMessageList(mr);
```

This is the info provided by the web service host

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:urn1="urn:green:partner:ws:schema:FilingInfo">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
<urn1:getcourtList>
<urn1:courtListRequest/>
</urn1:getcourtList>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>

<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:urn1="urn:green:partner:ws:schema:FilingInfo">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
<urn1:getMessageList>
<urn1:messageListRequest>
<urn1:latestMessagePullTimestamp>?</urn1:latestMessagePullTimestamp>
</urn1:messageListRequest>
</urn1:getMessageList>
</x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

we've got request and response pairs for each operation in the webservice. think like request => input, response => output, operation => method.

the webservice is an API. things that consume APIs are clients. the WSDL describes the API's operations and their requests and responses. tools like visual studio know how to read WSDLs and build C# code to perform those (SOAP) operations under-the-hood. this is the client (here `FilingInfoClient`). visual studio'll also generate classes representing each request and response.

this allows for a familiar programming experience. you call a method, give it some input, and it returns some output.

```
using (var client = new FilingInfoClient())
{
    var request = new courtListRequest
    {
        //TODO fill in relevant properties
    };
    var response = client.getCourtList(request);
}
```

Comment: So looking at that I'm not that far off. But, I just pasted that in and ran it as is and I'm still getting the same type mismatch error and the response has 1ff8 as leading characters.  Thanks, but something is stil not right.  If I runt the same request in SoapUI I get a result without the error, which is good. But the headers sent appear to be exactly the same as what I am sending from C#.  Weird and I have no idea what to look at.

Comment: Also tried this on the second method and the response was the datetimeproperty was not provided.  Used this code:                using (var client = new FilingInfoClient())
            {

                var request = new messageListRequest
                {
                    
                    latestMessagePullTimestamp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)

                    //TODO fill in relevant properties
                };
                var response = client.getMessageList(request);
            }       Thanks for any help or thoughts.